# How to write contact from Etherscan

Tags: solidity, metamask, contract-deployment, etherscan

I am trying to interact with this one inch contract 0x1111111254EEB25477B68fb85Ed929f73A960582 on Etherscan. I have never interacted with contacts this way so please start from the basics. I want to preform function 24.

https://etherscan.io/writecontract/index?m=light&v=21.10.1.1&a=0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582&n=mainnet&p=#collapse24

I want to swap ETH for USDT and send it to a seperate address than the one initiating it. Here is the screenshot of me trying and the metamask error I am getting [image]
I want to swap 0.001 ETH for USDT about $2.3 at time of writing. I dont care really about gas its just to learn. Plese let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you never have interacted with a contract that way I'd suggest to start using their app.